# Telerik Kendo Angular UI DropDownList block resizing

Tags: css, angular, drop-down-menu, kendo-ui

I'm using Kendo for Angular DropDownList with filtering. The width of the list is fitted to the size of the longest item in the list.

```
<kendo-dropdownlist
        [data]="data"
        [filterable]="true"
        [textField]="'text'"
        [valueField]="'value'"
        [popupSettings]=" {width: 'auto' }"
        (filterChange)="handleFilter($event)"
    >
    </kendo-dropdownlist>
```

But is it possible to 'freeze' further resizing? When I filter the list, I would like to have its width the same as at the beginning.

Here is the plnkr: 
https://plnkr.co/edit/ROWl4McPNlyhMz1srDhc?p=preview

I would like the list to stay wide even after I type e.g. 'sh' in the filter input.